# Shift multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro to insert a selected number of rows in an active cell, but I can't get the same to work with columns as well.

For rows I have

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngIns As Long

lngIns = InNo.Value

If Not refRng.Value = "" Then
    Rows(CStr(Selection.row) & ":" & CStr(CLng(Selection.row) + lngIns - 1)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
```

I tried to do the same for columns (and then combine the two statements with `If opt`), so the code is

```
If Not refRng.Value = "" Then
    Columns(CStr(Selection.column) & ":" & CStr(CLng(Selection.column) + lngIns - 1)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlRight
End If
```

but this results in a 1004 Run-time Error (Application-defined or object-defined error). What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) and [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
If Not refRng.Value = vbNullString Then
    Selection.EntireColumn.Resize(ColumnSize:=lngIns).Insert Shift:=xlRight
End If
```

Same for the row

```
If Not refRng.Value = vbNullString Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Resize(RowSize:=lngIns).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that Select should be avoided